# hdparm on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, hard-drive

On Linux, I can verify and change the low level parameters of my disk drive using [hdparm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/). Is there an utility providing the same capabilities for OS X, or perhaps some other way of manipulating the parameters?

Anders

Comment: I kinda wish you did not accept an answer yet.  It does not seems like there is an acceptable answer to your question given. I would also like to know about some low-level tools on OS X. (no offense to Graham Perrin intended) e.g. `hdparm -r0 /dev/disk2s1` On FreeBSD there is `atacontrol`.

Comment: @JonathanKomar perhaps `smartctl`? https://joernhees.de/blog/2011/09/16/mac-os-x-harddisk-high-load-cycle-counts/#more-360

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## pmset

`pmset` can manipulate power management settings, for example:

```
sh-3.2$ pmset -g | grep disksleep
 disksleep            10
sh-3.2$ sudo pmset disksleep 0
Warning: Idle sleep timings for "Battery Power" may not behave as expected.
- Disk sleep should be non-zero whenever system sleep is non-zero.
sh-3.2$ pmset -g | grep disksleep
 disksleep            0
sh-3.2$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.8.2
BuildVersion:   12C60
sh-3.2$
```

[pmset(1) OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)

## EFI and SATA

https://discussions.apple.com/message/11856660#11856660 (2010-07-07) reminds me:

> … Engineering has provided the following information:
>
> > This behavior is not the result of OS level disk spindown commands.
> >     There is an EFI change for SATA bus speed; and the suggested
> >     workaround is to run hdapm to set a new power management level on the
> >     disk itself.
> >
> > This isn't an OS power management behavior, it's a tricky interaction
> >     between device firmware and EFI's configuration of the SATA interface.
> >     We commission drives from our vendors with different behaviors than
> >     the drives available generally on the market, and that is why the
> >     generic replacement does not support the features as you expect. …

(Side note: an Apple Support Communities bug may cause the wrong set of messages to appear. If that bug bites, then instead [browse](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2250690?start=165&tstart=0) to the 2010-07-07 point in the topic.)

## hdapm

http://mckinlay.net.nz/hdapm/

> A Mac OS X command line utility for setting the power management (APM) level for ATA hard drives.
>
> It can be used to eliminate "chirping" or "clicking when idle" noises in some HDDs.
>
> **Compatibility**
>
> - OS X 10.5 or higher.
> - ATA/SATA hard disk with APM support.
> - Does not work with external USB or Firewire drives. …

> … (Aug 25, 2012) version 1.2. …

## SpindownHD

From past use of tools from Apple Developer, I set aside a copy of **SpindownHD**.app 4.6.2 (227.9) *Copyright © 2003-2005 Apple Computer, Inc.*, part of the old CHUD (Computer Hardware Understanding Developer) tools – apparently OK for polling. However: as some of the KEXTs from that period are incompatible with modern versions of the OS, I don't know whether it's sane to use this app for sleep settings (for all disks).

[image: 2012-10-26 screenshot of old SpindownHD.app]

Answer (score 3):

http://missig.org/julian/projects/macosx/

"diskutil - A whole set of utilities like fsck, fdisk, tune2fs, and hdparm combined."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility

"Disk Utility functions may also be accessed from the Mac OS X command line with the diskutil and hdiutil commands."

There seems to be no port of hdparm for OSX unfortunately.

Comment: Diskutil, though fairly comprehensive, does not allow the kind of low level access I'm looking for.

Comment: What specifically do you need?

Comment: In this case I'm looking to disable NCQ and the disk write cache.

Comment: @Anders did you find anything? I'm looking to disable automatic fsck.